# How to get data from GraphQL by filtering particular variable?

Tags: node.js, graphql

Below you can see my graphql method. From this, I can get the first data of the database that city is equal to 'London'. But I want to view all the data related to the city of London. Can anyone help?

```
//Graphql method   
async getByCity(_,{city}){
        try{
            const ByCity = await Employee.findOne({city});
            if(ByCity ){
                return ByCity ;
            }else{
                throw new Error('Employee not found');
            }
        }catch(err){
            throw new Error(err);
        }
    },

//Query
query($city: String!){
  getByCity(city: $city) {
    id
  }
}

//Query Variable
{
  "city": "london"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Employee.findOne({city})` seems like you are fetching only one entry here. I am not sure what library you are using. If you can specify the library  can give a more comprehensive answer

try:

`Employee.find({city})`

Comment: I used apollo-server-express and mongoose